# MS build and NUnit adapter - how to parameterize tests

Tags: parameters, msbuild, nunit

Is there a way how to parameterize tests running with NUnit as part of build on TFS? What I'm looking for is to have the possibility to run the same batch of tests with multiple sets of parameters - like specified browser, start URL, etc.

I know, that with MSTest I would use multiple .runsettings files and acquired parameters at runtime - is there something like that but for NUnit test adapter?

Answer (score 0):

In NUnit you use the `TestCase` attribute to pass input arguments to a test function like this:

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

You can use this to pass data such as the browser, start url etc. into your test together with the result you're expecting.

See the [documentation](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that I'm fully aware of it. And I can even parameterize entire TestFixture like that. But here the scenario is a bit different - to be more specific, I want to specify my UI Selenium tests to run first with Chrome, then with Firefox, etc.
Runsettings file would be perfect, however I haven't figure it out how to read it from this NUnit environment ...

Comment: Of course, there is nothing in NUnit to read the RunSettings file, since that file is specific to VisualStudio and TFS. 

There could be something in the NUnit VS adapter to read parameters from that file (we'd have to add it) but first NUnit would need a way to pass a general set of parameters into the run. That's been requested (search our issues) but isn't yet implemented. :-(